# Turn on Wifi using a Widget

Tags: android

i need to toggle wifi on and off when user clicks a widget icon...

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
else
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

How do i implement it using pendingIntents?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Create a `BroadcastReceiver` that contains your `setWifiEnabled()` logic.

Step #2: Declare that receiver with a `<receiver>` element in the manifest.

Step #3: Use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent` with the button in your app widget, pointing to this `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0):

Download below example it will help you

https://github.com/siddhpuraamitr/WIfi-Toggle-Widget

Answer (score 0):

**From Android-10 (API level 29)**

According to `documentation`, Apps will not be able to turn `Wi-Fi OFF/ON` programmatically anymore from `Android-10` `API level 29`**[Until google provides an alternative solution]**.

See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075794/4854891) for details.